# Can the forumula $(n-1)!$ be used for a second set of items to be arranged in a circular permutation?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I was trying to solve a question which asked me to arrange 5 men and 4 women in a round table in such a way that no 2 women sit together.

For this I used the gap approach and found the number of gaps formed after permutating the 5 men by using the formula $(n-1)!$ and was left with 5 gaps for 4 women to be seated in.
I used $5C4$ and then arranged the women using $(n-1)!$ , but I found in my solutions book that they have not used the circular permutation formula, rather just $n!$.

Am I missing something here and is it a general rule that $(n-1)!$ can't be used more than once in a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were no men on the table, the women could be permuted in $4!/4=3!$ ways. But once the men's seats are fixed, each of the $4$ seating arrangements of the women which were earlier treated as equivalent have to now be treated as distinct because of the changed relative position of men and women. This graph may help you understand better:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

In both pictures the order of the seating of the women is identical, but because the relative seating between the men and women gets changed, they will have to be treated as different seating arrangements.

Comment: Ah wonderfully explained, the diagram made it click for me

Answer (score 0):

When you used 5C4 to choose from the 5 gaps between the men, you already accounted for the circular permutation. If the 5 men were arranged in a line, you would have 6 gaps.

The (n-1)! becomes redundant once you have already accounted for the circular permutation.